# SQL Server 2008 - split multi-value column into rows with unique values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, split, pivot

In a SQL Server 2008 database, I have a column with multiple values separated by semi-colons.  Some values contain colons.  Sample data:

```
key:value;key2:value;blah;foo;bar;A sample value:whee;others
key:value;blah;bar;others
A sample value:whee
```

I want to get all the unique values from each row in separate rows:

```
key:value
key2:value
blah
foo
bar
A sample value:whee
others
```

I've looked at various `split` functions, but they all seem to deal with hard-coded strings, not strings coming from a column in a table.  How can I do this?

**Edit:** Thomas' answer got it!  Here was my final query:

```
With SampleInputs As
    (
    select distinct myColumn from [myDatabase].[dbo].myTable where myColumn != ''
    )
    , XmlCte As
    (
    Select Cast( '<z>' + Replace( myColumn, ';', '</z><z>' ) + '</z>' As xml ) As XmlValue
    From SampleInputs As I
    )
Select Distinct Y.z.value('.','nvarchar(max)') As Value
From XmlCte
    Cross Apply XmlValue.nodes('//z') Y(z)
```

I'm guessing the `XmlValue.nodes` and `Y.z.value` stuff is magic.  O_o

Comment: Would you be able to use c#, or do you have to use tsql?

Comment: I would prefer for this to be done entirely in T-SQL, within SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With SampleInputs As
    (
    Select 'key:value;key2:value;blah;foo;bar;A sample value:whee;others' As [Data]
    Union All Select 'key:value;blah;bar;others' 
    Union All Select 'A sample value:whee'
    )
    , XmlCte As
    (
    Select Cast( '<z>' + Replace( I.[Data], ';', '</z><z>' ) + '</z>' As xml ) As XmlValue
    From SampleInputs As I
    )
Select Distinct Y.z.value('.','nvarchar(max)') As Value
From XmlCte
    Cross Apply XmlValue.nodes('//z') Y(z)
```

---

**Update**

Here's a version of the above that handles entities:

```
With SampleInputs As
    (
    Select 'key:value;key2:value;blah;foo;bar;A sample value:whee;others' As [Data]
    Union All Select 'key:value;blah;bar;others' 
    Union All Select 'A sample value:whee'
    Union All Select 'A sample value:<Oops>'
    )
    , XmlGoo As
    (
    Select Cast(
            Replace(
                Replace( Cast( Z.XmlValue As nvarchar(max) ), '{{', '<z>' )
                , '}}', '</z>')
            As Xml ) As Xmlvalue
    From    (
            Select Cast(
                    (
                    Select '{{' + Replace( [Data], ';', '}}{{' ) + '}}'
                    From SampleInputs
                    For Xml Path(''), type
                    ) As Xml ) As XmlValue
            ) As Z
    )
Select Distinct Z.data.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
From XmlGoo
    Cross Apply XmlValue.nodes('/z') Z(data)
```

Comment: You need to take care of `<` and `&` in the data if you use this technique.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson - That can be overcome. Have posted a version that will allow for Xml reserved symbols.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson - (Obviously if `{` or `}` could be in the source data, a different marker should be used.)

Answer (score 4):

With a split function you use cross apply:

```
select distinct SS.part
from YourTable
  cross apply dbo.SplitString(YourColumn, ';') as SS
```

Here the SplitString takes two arguments, the string column and the separator and has a column called `part` where the values are returned.