# how to split the column data to different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table `Sitetable` with a column that contains multiple values separated by comma (,) and would like to split it so I get each Site on its own row but with the same Number in front.

So my input data would be:

```
Number             Site 
952240             2-78,2-89
952423             2-78,2-83,8-34
```

and my expected output would be:

```
Number             Site 
952240             2-78 
952240             2-89 
952423             2-78  
952423             2-83 
952423             8-34
```

Comment: Someone,Please format my question. I dont know the way of foematting the above.

Comment: Instead of trying to "split" a row, you should re-design your data model and normalize your tables...

Comment: Hmm, with Oracle I'd transform the comma-separated list into a `VARRAY OF VARCHAR2` and then unnest and join that array again. But I don't think SQL Server supports array types?

Comment: @Bohemain: Thanks for formatting.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Iam new working with sql and in learning stage. I know about normalization. But can you please help me out to analyse how it is applicable with above case.

Comment: @Lukas Eder : Is there any other way of sloving my problem in sql server? Could you please help me out.

Comment: @Pearl: Apart from trying to write a stored function returning a cursor, I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good example of [SplitStringToTable](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=590692).

Answer (score 0):

(Not directly the answer you were looking for, but as you asked for this in the comment...)

The reason why you need this "hack" is because your tables are not normalized. If you move the relation between site and number into its own table, your problem goes away:

```
 number_table (number, ...)
 site_table (site_id, site_name, ...)
 assigned_site (number, site_id)
```

With foreign keys from asssigned_site to number_table and site_table.

If your tables were structured that way, a simple join would do what you want:

```
 SELECT nb.number, agn.site_id, sit.site_name
 FROM number_table nb
    JOIN assigned_site agn ON nb.number = agn.number
    JOIN site sit ON sit.site_id = agn.site_id
```

The `site_table` is only necessary if your sites have additional attributes apart from the actual identifier (as in my example with the site_name).

If your site *only* consists of the ID then you don't need the `site_table` and your problem is reduced to a simple `SELECT * FROM assigned_site`.

Comment: Yes i understand how normalization helps me to get the format i need. But, i have data in the above form in one table. Could you please give me an idea to split it in to tables like above.

Answer (score 0):

This one way to do what you want. Just replace `@T` with `Sitetable` in the query below.

```
declare @T table
(
  Number int,
  Site varchar(20)
)

insert into @T values 
(952240, '2-78,2-89'),
(952423, '2-78,2-83,8-34')

select T1.Number,
       T3.I.value('.', 'varchar(5)') as Site
from @T as T1
  cross apply (select cast('<i>'+replace(T1.Site, ',', '</i><i>')+'</i>' as xml)) as T2(X)
  cross apply T2.X.nodes('i') as T3(I)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is already solved in:
[SQL Server 2008 - split multi-value column into rows with unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392340/sql-server-2008-split-multi-value-column-into-rows-with-unique-values)

In your case,

```
With Inputs As
(
    select 952240 as Number, '2-78,2-89' as [Site]
    union 
    select 952423, '2-78,2-83,8-34'
)
, XCte As
(
    Select number, Cast( '<data>' + Replace( Inputs.[Site], ',', '</data><data>' ) + '</data>' As xml ) As XValue
    From Inputs
)
Select Number, Y.data.value('.','nvarchar(max)') As Site
From XCte
    Cross Apply XValue.nodes('//data') Y(data)
```