# How to parse data, split into multiple rows, and save to a flat file using SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have source data as follows:

```
ID  Data
1   text text text
2   text text text
```

In SSIS, I need to make a transformation which will result in

```
ID  Data
1   text
1   text
1   text
2   text
2   text
2   text
```

The destination file needs to be a flat file. Is it possible to do this transformation? How? I tried a Derived column with `ID + REPLACE((DT_WSTR,4000)Data," ","\n")`, but that seems to be an incorrect approach.

Comment: Agreed: not derived column, because you want new *rows*, not new columns.  (Aside, FYI: REPLACE's first parm is a column name or string literal, not a datatype, and DT_WSTR is an SSIS datatype.)  I suggest splitting in SQL rather than SSIS, for faster development.  If it's **always 3** text blocks -- then you could simply do 3 `INSERT` commands to a table, then use the final table as your source.  If it's not always 3 text blocks, then take a look at the answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392340/sql-server-2008-split-multi-value-column-into-rows-with-unique-values

Comment: It looks like you reposted this question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911117/sql-separate-row.  In the future, rather than take people's time on 2 questions... please **edit** the first question you posted, or leave comments on it.

Comment: @Doug_Ivison: I don't agree with your comment - the other question is asking about a different technology - SQL vs SSIS.

Comment: I worked out the problem with derived column and replace string function + guide at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/34ce1b87-fee7-48c9-b3aa-9615de138bbc/how-to-replace-multiple-blanks-into-one?forum=sqlintegrationservices . Thanks guys for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked out this problem with the Derived Column and it's REPLACE string function so the spaces in texts are replaced by `|` + guide at **[Split multi value column into multiple records](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.se/2012/11/split-multi-value-column-into-multiple.html)**

Comment: Glad you resolved it!  For the sake of anyone finding this page... could you share how you split each row, into multiple rows (like you showed in your question)?  The link you've given has a good examples of REPLACE, but in all its examples, one row still produces only one row.

Comment: Thanks for notice. I attached wrong link by accident. Given the link in my answer, you can see how the work has been done. It provides full guide. Should you need to know more, please let me know.

Comment: Very interesting... and useful:  adding a Script Component, with `Output0Buffer.AddRow()` in the script.

Comment: Yes, I found it useful as well. Clever solution which works as it should.

Answer (score -2):

In SSIS this is achieved using the UnPivot Transformation:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723.aspx

Comment: The data to split is in a single column therefore the UnPivot cannot be used. The Script Component mentioned bij DNac will work for this situation...