# Sql query to create single row to multiple row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table as given below

```
ID           Value
-----        ----------
1            10,20,30
```

I need the result as

```
ID         Value
---        -------
1           10
1           20
1           30
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why have you stored `10,20,30` at all? Isn't it possible to store it already as you want it in the result? So you should create a new table with a foreign-key to the first table. That process is called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: I know you may think you are earning space in the way you are storing them, but you are going to lose processing time displaying them. I agree with @Tim , have separate rows. Even have another table for One-Many or Many-Many relationship. This is why we have Relational DBs.

Comment: Is it possible to get the result by using sql query?

Comment: @user3433179: yes, there are already many duplicates, f.e.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392340/sql-server-2008-split-multi-value-column-into-rows-with-unique-values .But instead of splitting the string i would really change the model.

Comment: 100% agree that you should change your model and use the relational database in the manor it was intended. However, everything you need to know, and probably more is covered in this article by Aaron Bertrand: **[Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)**. I don't believe there is anything I could add to this in an answer so I won't even try.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
  ;with tmp(Id, value, Data) as (
select Id,  LEFT(value, CHARINDEX(',',value+',')-1),
    STUFF(value, 1, CHARINDEX(',',value+','), '')
from @Testdata
union all
select Id, LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1),
    STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '')
from tmp
where Data > ''
)
select Id,  value
from tmp
order by Id
```

Possible duplicate [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
 SELECT A.ID,  
        Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Value  
   FROM (SELECT ID,  
              CAST ('<V>' + REPLACE(Value, ',', '</V><V>') + '</V>' AS XML) AS Value  
         FROM  YourTable
        ) AS A 
        CROSS APPLY Value.nodes ('/V') AS Split(a);
```