# SQL - Split Column by ; symbol column[1], column[2] to make seperate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, progress

I have a column, where the value is being split by ; symbols.

On my odbc driver I use Progress SQL that allows me to split the following.

```
select "address" FROM TABLE.EXAMPLE
```

Result

```
 google;1 example street;london;
```

which I could split by using [] and the required instance number

```
select "address"[1], "address"[2], "address"[3] FROM TABLE.EXAMPLE
```

result

```
address1    address2             address3     
google      1 example street     London
```

I am trying to recreate this once uploaded to a sql server.
I am struggling to query the same column to allow splitting the columns into separate fields.

```
sy.[address][1],sy.[address][1],sy.[address][1]
```

resulting in

```
address                         address                         address
google;1 example street;london; google;1 example street;london; google;1 example street;london;
```

which doesn't help. 
This way of splitting the data was a lot easier rather then using functions and declarations to split the string in the column.

Can someone please let me know the required language to do the split.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 - split multi-value column into rows with unique values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392340/sql-server-2008-split-multi-value-column-into-rows-with-unique-values)

Comment: Do you mean `postgresql`?

Comment: ...and does "uploaded to a sql server" mean _the_ Microsoft SQL Server, or something else?

Comment: This is the thing, I could use functions to be able to cleverly separate the column looking for values in between ; symbols.

Comment: Its is just frustrating that the current sql language that I am using allows me to query so easily to split the column. Currently querying a Progress Database, not a postgresql database.

Comment: Once again: '...and does "uploaded to a sql server" mean _the_ Microsoft SQL Server, or something else?'

Comment: Sorry, yes I use Visual Studio to ETL Progress Database to Microsoft SQL Server Database. I have done this but I come across the above struggle when querying the data using SSMS

Comment: Are you trying something similar in this link : https://raresql.com/2015/08/22/sql-server-how-to-split-one-column-into-multiple-columns/